# How do I solve this external error that PHP generates? PHP 8.2+ Laravel 11

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry, I'm not very good at English, I'm using a translator to help me. I have been guided by a video to create a database website and this error has been generated:

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/####/AppData/Local/Temp/$Metadata$/209067CB$manual/false.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "PHP2002",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot redeclare constant 'false'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 12
}]
```

false.php code

```
<?php // Generated code

/**
 * See Booleans .
 * @var bool
 */
const false = _ /* value is not documented */;
```

my TagIndex.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TagIndex extends Component
{
    public $showTagModal = false;
    
    public function showCreateModal()
    {
        $this->showTagModal = true;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.tag-index');
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Is your native language Espanol? If so, check this site: https://es.stackoverflow.com ... Not sure about the video mentioned, but the error is clear: `Cannot redeclare constant 'false'` means that false is already defined somewhere, and what you have is redeclaring the original definition.

Comment: There isn't much info here to go on - what generated that error and `false.php` file?  `false` is a reserved word, you can't use it as a variable name, constant, property etc.  The generated code seems to be trying to do that with `const false = _ `, but why or where that comes from we can't see.

Comment: You cannot do `const false =` because [`false` is a language constant](https://php.net/false). Fiddling with language constructs looks way too advanced for a create web site tutorial. I think you just an error while typing.